# Add value to points in google chart

Tags: laravel, charts, google-visualization

I want to display the values on all points of both lines to my google chart.

Im trying with annotation but cant get them to be display. Would love if someone could help me.
De first two values is the lines, and i would like to display the values of both on respective line dots all the time, not when im hovering them.
The values be displayed like on this picture:
[Chart with no values displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZJlW.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
        
      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          

            ['Date','New Errors','Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6','Value7','Value8','Value9','Value10','Value11','Value12','Value13','Value14','Value15',],
            ['2023-06-18',101,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,16,17,0,9,0,57,],
            ['2023-06-19',141,34,1,0,1,6,25,0,0,0,7,13,0,14,0,74,],
            ['2023-06-20',153,0,0,0,0,13,2,0,0,0,13,22,0,8,0,95,],
            ['2023-06-21',138,90,0,0,0,23,1,0,0,0,8,13,0,9,0,84,],
            ['2023-06-22',157,0,2,0,0,26,0,0,0,1,13,0,0,6,0,82,],
            ['2023-06-23',122,72,0,0,0,23,1,2,0,0,11,0,1,0,0,57,],
            ['2023-06-24',104,62,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,33,0,0,9,0,48,],
            ['2023-06-25',94,57,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,6,0,53,],
            ['2023-06-26',74,4,0,0,4,1,1,0,0,0,14,13,1,0,0,24,],
            ['2023-06-27',13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,4,0,2,]
         

        ]);

        var options = {
          title : 'Value',
          vAxis: {title: 'Value', minValue: 0},
          aggregationTarget: 'category',
          hAxis: {title: 'Day'},
          seriesType: 'bars',
          bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
          isStacked: true,
          pointSize: 5,
          series: {0: {type: 'line',role: 'annotation '},
                    1: {type: 'line', role: 'annotation '}
            },
          
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
```

Also tried adding, but with the same result (added view to chart.draw also ;) ):

```
 var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
            calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 1,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation"
        },]);
```

Answer (score 0):

for annotations, you can use a [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#annotationrole).

to define a column role, you can use a data view, or add directly to the data table.
the column should have the following properties.

```
{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}
```

and there should be an annotation column, following each column that needs an annotation.
following is an example for adding directly to the data table.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Date','New Errors',{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},'Value1',{type: 'string', role: 'annotation'},'Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6','Value7','Value8','Value9','Value10','Value11','Value12','Value13','Value14','Value15'],
  ['2023-06-18',101,'101',0,'0',0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,16,17,0,9,0,57],
  // ...
]);
```

if you prefer to use a data view, same rules apply, add the annotation column, after each series column that should be annotated.
in the data view, you also need to include the index of all the other columns that should be displayed on the chart.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: 'stringify',
  sourceColumn: 1,
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'
}, 2, {
  calc: 'stringify',
  sourceColumn: 2,
  type: 'string',
  role: 'annotation'
}, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);
```

see following working example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date','New Errors','Value1','Value2','Value3','Value4','Value5','Value6','Value7','Value8','Value9','Value10','Value11','Value12','Value13','Value14','Value15'],
    ['2023-06-18',101,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,16,17,0,9,0,57],
    ['2023-06-19',141,34,1,0,1,6,25,0,0,0,7,13,0,14,0,74],
    ['2023-06-20',153,0,0,0,0,13,2,0,0,0,13,22,0,8,0,95],
    ['2023-06-21',138,90,0,0,0,23,1,0,0,0,8,13,0,9,0,84],
    ['2023-06-22',157,0,2,0,0,26,0,0,0,1,13,0,0,6,0,82],
    ['2023-06-23',122,72,0,0,0,23,1,2,0,0,11,0,1,0,0,57],
    ['2023-06-24',104,62,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,33,0,0,9,0,48],
    ['2023-06-25',94,57,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,6,0,53],
    ['2023-06-26',74,4,0,0,4,1,1,0,0,0,14,13,1,0,0,24],
    ['2023-06-27',13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,4,0,2]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);

  var options = {
    title : 'Value',
    vAxis: {title: 'Value', minValue: 0},
    aggregationTarget: 'category',
    hAxis: {title: 'Day'},
    seriesType: 'bars',
    bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
    isStacked: true,
    pointSize: 5,
    series: {
      0: {type: 'line'},  // roles are not defined within the series option, only series type
      1: {type: 'line'}
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```